# C# NullReferenceException on GetElementById HtmlElement

Tags: c#

this is inside my sample.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testingID">hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i have this code in c# that i want to prompt is the world "hello" inside the ***div*** element with the id **testingID**

```
private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = string.Format("{0}/sample.html", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        WebBrowser webb = new WebBrowser();

        webb.Navigate(url);

        var doc = webb.Document;
        HtmlElement elem = doc.GetElementById("testingID");
        MessageBox.Show(elem.InnerText);
    }
```

but i get *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* on *MessageBox.Show(elem.InnerText);*

a little help here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, you are trying to access the element, but the document is not loaded at the moment. Move `doc.GetElementById("testingID");` in WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that elem is null because an element with an ID of 'testingID' is not being found in the document. Try stepping through with a debugger and verifying that elem is not null. Alternatively, try something like the following:

```
if (elem != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(elem.InnerText);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show('No element found!');
}
```